# Mistake in Karl Pearson's 1900 paper introducing the chi-squared distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, st.statistics, ho.history-overview, matrix-inverse

### Background

I'm reading Karl Pearson's 1900 paper titled:

[*On the criterion that a given system of deviations from the probable in the case of a correlated system of variables is such that it can be reasonably supposed to have arisen from random sampling*](http://www.medicine.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/Proportion/Pearson1900.pdf)

I paraphrase the opening. He supposes $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ is a system of random variables following a multivariate normal distribution centered at the origin. Then he asserts the probability density of the vector $\langle x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \rangle$ is
$$
Z = Z_0 \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2\det S}\sum_i \sum_j S_{pq} x_p x_q\right)\,,
$$
where

- $S$ is the covariance matrix of $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$
- $S_{pq}$ is the "minor obtained by striking out the $p$th row and $q$th column" of the covariance matrix
- $Z_0$ is an unspecified constant.

This appears inconsistent with the multivariate normal density function from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function), which involves a matrix inverse. These two expressions for the density function can be reconciled using Cramer's rule, but only if what Karl Pearson meant by "minor" is what we today would call a "cofactor."

### Question

In 1900, did the word "minor" refer to what we would call a "cofactor"?

Comment: the difference between minor and cofactor is only a sign, isn't it likely that Pearson was just sloppy/imprecise? (the words themselves both were first used around 1850)

Comment: Titles of articles these days just aren’t what they used to be...!

Answer (score 2):

Carlo Beenakker was [correct](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396921/mistake-in-karl-pearsons-1900-paper-introducing-the-chi-squared-distribution#comment1016351_396921). (Thank you.) The formula given by Pearson is wrong (assuming no differences in terminology). The paper should say "cofactor" instead of "minor."

Take $n=2$. Choose an arbitrary positive semidefinite matrix $M$ to use as the covariance matrix of $\langle x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \rangle$. Numerically compute the covariance matrix $N$ of the distribution described by Pearson. Observe $N\neq M$.

Code here:
https://gist.github.com/Chris-Kimmel/0e9f1e905034dbe2092694cb580787ce